# Grid columns to be sized by content width but constrained by width of the grid

Tags: xaml, resize, grid, windows-phone-8

I have the following markup:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock x:Name="Col1" Text="Text1" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Col2" Text="Text12" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

If I put a lot of text in `Col1` it exceeds the screen and `Col2` could not be seen at all.  I would like to change that behavior such that if there's too much text in `Col1` then it's width gets reduced so that `Col2` could be fully seen.

On the other hand if I change markup to this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock x:Name="Col1" Text="Text1" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Col2" Text="Text12" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Here are images the illustrate how I want TextBlocks to behave:

Combined width of two TextBlocks is smaller than screen so they go one after another.
[image]

First Text block is very long so it is cropped in order to contain second TextBlock within screen.
[image]

Then everything is OK when `Col1` has a lot of text but when the amount of text is small there is a gap between `Col1` and `Col2`. What should I do to get desired behavior in both situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised;

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    
    <TextBlock x:Name="Col1" Text="Text1" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Col2" Text="Text12" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</Grid>
```

Then Keep in mind to limit their overall size this would be placed in a parent panel container like another `Grid`

Comment: Well not quite. When combined width of both TextBlock's is less then screen size I want first TextBlock to be followed by second without space between them (so precentage won't do). If combined width is bigger than screen size, I want first TextBlock to be reduced so it does not push second off the screen.

Comment: I think I got ya, try the edited version of the first example.

Comment: Chris, this still does not quite cut it. I've aupdated my question and provided images to illustrate what I want.

Comment: Give the revised version a shot.

Comment: does not work from .Net v3.5 to v4.5.1. TextBlock is clipped but not wrapped. Additionally, the first column shrink to nothing when the second TextBlock gets too big. Testing by creating a C# Wpf project in VS2013 and adjusting Framework version in stages from v4.5.1 to v3.5.

Comment: @George - Then you're doing your layout incorrectly in regards to your use of these Framework Elements. Also (yet not that it matters in this case) the questions was for windows phone, which is based on silverlight so a wpf project would have minor differences. I would say ask your specific question with code to represent your current issue.